# ServiceRegistry constructor fails with ClassCastException on concrete class

Tags: java, classcastexception, jmf, service-provider

Trying to use `javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry` to dynamically register request processors for an `HttpServlet`:

```
    private static final Class PROVIDER_CLASS = IRequestProcessor.class;

 private void loadProviders() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  _serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(PROVIDER_CLASS));
 }
```

The error I get is:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.confused.servlet.GetStandardCodesProcessor
javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:103
org.confused.servlet.MyServlet.loadProviders(.java:100)
 org.confused.servlet.MyServlet.checkProviders(.java:106)
 org.confused.servlet.MyServlet.service(.java:44)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

The class `GetStandardCodesProcessor` implements `IRequestProcessor`.
The call `ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders()` is getting a list of classes from the file `META-INF/services/org.confused.servlet.IRequestProcessor`.
It seems I am missing a nuance about how to pass in the iterator from `ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders()`.

[This page](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=49083) shows pretty much what I'm doing, albeit assigning the the return from lookupProviders() to an untyped Iterator, which in turn gets passed to the `ServiceRegistry` constructor.  That technique gives the same error for me.

Lastly, I am running this in Eclipse Gallileo (build 20100218-1602), if that matters.

Regards,
Drew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used this SPI class before, however, from the [API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.html), the constructor of `ServiceRegistry` takes in an `Iterator` with categories, not providers. You may want to register your providers with `registerServiceProviders()` instead?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.
While I could 'manually' add the classes via registerServiceProviders(), I was looking to take advantage of the automagic class recognition that ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders() offers.  I thought the Iterator in ServiceRegistry(Iterator<Class<?>>) was expected to be the list of classes to register; is it looking for the interfaces instead?

Comment: But the truth is, the constructor(Iterator<Class<?>>) is not meant for providers to register but categories of providers.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.
I'd +1 your answer, but I'm not worthy yet. :(

Comment: No worries. You can mark it "answered" I suppose, but if you can't, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

yclian, thanks for the "bonk on the head".

The constructor is indeed expecting the list of 'categories', which are the **interfaces** that the registry can search for.  Once I corrected that part, and populated the ServiceRegistry as you said, the rest works great.

The new code:

```
private void loadProviders() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Iterator iterCategories = (Collections.singletonList(PROVIDER_CLASS)).iterator();
    _serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistry(iterCategories);
    _serviceRegistry.registerServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(PROVIDER_CLASS));
}
```